# Assigning the same value to different cells according to the rank of a matching cell's group

Tags: excel, formula

I have an Excel sheet that has values repeating in different rows of the same column (`Obtain Marks`). In `RANKS` column I want a grade assigned.

My problem is assigning the same rank to cells having the same `Obtain Marks` values.

How do I assign the same rank to the same `Obtained Marks` using an Excel formula?

```
Obtain Marks       RANKS                  
212                  1                               
212                  1                                
212                  1                               
211                  2                                
210                  3                                   
209                  4                                
209                  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Obtain Marks` is in A1 and is sorted in order, if you want grouped by *rank* then I suggest in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=RANK(A2,A$2:A$7,)
```

If you post includes under RANK the desired output then I suggest instead `1` in B2 and in B3 and copied down to suit:

```
  =IF(A2=A3,B2,B2+1)
```

Either way each group should have a distinct value.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive a pseudo-RANK.UNIQUE formula by modifying an old standard method of a [SUMPRODUCT-style](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) COUNT.UNIQUE formula.

[image: RANK_UNIQUE]

The formula in B2 is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$8>=A2)/COUNTIF(A$2:A$8, A$2:A$8&""))
```

Fill down as necessary.